# Fetch value and name in a select, from form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fetch several data from a select list.
I have the value as `$_POST['valt_skift']`.
But I also like to `send name`.
How can I do this?

This is what I got:

```
<select id="valt_skift" name="valt_skift">
  <option></option>
  <?php
    //Loop put result
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
      echo '<option name="skift_name['.$row['skift_name'].']" value="'.$row["skift_type"].'">'.$row["skift_namn"].'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

The fetch:

```
$query_params = array( 
    ':usr_skift' => $_POST['skift_name'][0], //Here is my question?!
    ':usr_skift_type' => $_POST['valt_skift']); //this will be the value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo within your code, you can't have `name` attribute within option value.If you want to get two values from the selected option then you can send it as

```
echo "<option value='{$row['skift_type']}@@@{$row['skift_name']}'>{$row['skift_name']}</option>";
```

This way you'll get the values along with the name within your `$_POST['valt_skift']` as

```
echo $_POST['valt_skift']; // your_value@@@your_name
```

now you can get `two values` within one `select option` using explode you can fetch them both as

```
$get_skift = explode('@@@',$_POST['valt_skift']);
$usr_skift_type = $get_skift[0];//your_value
$usr_skift = $get_skift[1];//your_name
```